# What does the dream scene signify in The Revenant?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-revenant

In the dream that Hugh Glass has in *The Revenant* it is shown that some men came and burnt all of the village. Glass killed one of the officers. Glass' wife was also killed. At some point a church is shown in the movie. But in the entire movie there is no explanation of these things.

Why did people come and burn all of the village, and why did they kill all the people out there?

Answer (score -1):

Well, The Revenant is by far my favorite movie, and I have seen it a thousand times. The scene where the Native village is burning, is simply fictional. It is placed in the movie to show background of how Hugh Glass became the father of Hawk. In real life, Hugh did not even have a son. In short, it was put in there simply for entertainment purposes.

Comment: That's all well and good, but historical inaccuracy notwithstanding, there has to be *something* behind that scene. Giving Hugh Glass background is a good reason, but still, what actually happened there and *what* background does it add to Hugh Glass?